# Column missing when I scaffold out views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a simple MVC application to perform CRUD operations on one table. I have an existing SQL Server database, so I guess this would be Entity Framework Database First.

For some reason, when I scaffold out the controller/view (using *MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework*), the first column is not added to Index.cshtml, Edit.cshtml, Details.cshtml, and Delete.cshtml.

But it *IS* added to Create.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think it was because it was the primary key field.